# Subcharts with the same dependency but different versions not getting deployed

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have two subcharts with the same dependency but different version. However if I try to deploy it, only the latest version is getting deployed and the older version is empty

This is my chart.yaml dependency and values.yaml below

```
dependencies:
  - name: vector
    alias: vector-agent
    version: 0.26.0
    repository: "https://helm.vector.dev"
    condition: vector-agent.enabled
  - name: vector
    alias: vector-infra
    version: 0.30.0
    repository: "https://helm.vector.dev"
    condition: vector-infra.enabled
```

```
vector-agent:
  enabled: false

vector-infra:
  enabled: false
```

Now when I try to deploy vector-agent after packaging the chart with an override file as below

```
vector-agent:
  enabled: true
  role: Agent
```

The helm template shows nothing

```
% helm template vector qlik-vector-2.0.1.tgz -f values.yaml 

%
```

However, it works when I try templating vector-infra with an override file.

Can someone please let me know the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `helm dependency update` command to update subcharts?

```
helm dependency update
```

You need to make sure the chart folder has the necessary subcharts. It wil look like:

```
|-- charts
|   |-- vector-0.26.0.tgz
|   |-- vector-0.30.0.tgz
```